# db.* files in /home from Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I see several db.* files in my /home directory, and it seems they come from perforce.  For example, some files are `db.archmap, db.bodtext, db.change, db.changex`

Are these files useful?  Can I delete them?  They are making my /home directory messy

Answer (score 4):

You have started a server using your home directory as the Perforce server's P4ROOT folder.  Those files are files that are generated from starting the server and cannot be deleted unless you want to hose your server installation.  It's not clear to me how you've started the server instance, so I'll try and cover multiple bases with my answer.

If you want to start up the server under your own account, you should set the P4ROOT environment variable and point it to where you want the server to store its files.  Alternatively, when you start the server, you can specify the root folder on the command line using the -r option:

```
p4d -r /home/mark/p4server
```

which would put the server's files into the directory called 'p4server' off of my home directory.

Typically it is best to run the perforce server using a user that is dedicated to running perforce.  I use a user called 'perforce'.  I set P4ROOT (and other variables) in that users environment.  If you cannot use a separate user, it might be easier to use the -r command line option that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Those files are only server files, not client files. So it is safe to delete them, but if you start the server back up it will recreate them. So you might want to uninstall the server.

Unless you are running a beta version, they have p4sandbox coming soon(maybe in the beta, I forget) which MAY create those files. I don't have a beta version, so I can't verify what new files the client may or may not create.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/schema/) to see what these files do/are for.

Comment: I'm also on this page myself :) But I'm wondering if they're deletable if we are only using the Perforce client... I believe p4d is installed, but there will be no local server running.

Comment: Ah I see. The client does not use these.